# Rollupjs Module didn't register its module

Tags: typescript, gulp, amd, rollupjs

I have a gulp task that runs rollup, compiles typescript and generates modules for dynamic imports:

```
const rollup = require('rollup');
const rolltypescript = require('rollup-plugin-typescript');
const babel = require('rollup-plugin-babel');
const resolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
const commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');
const omt = require('@surma/rollup-plugin-off-main-thread');

function typescript() {
  return rollup.rollup({
    input: 'app/scripts/main.ts',
    plugins: [
      omt(),
      rolltypescript(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      babel({
        babelrc: false,
        presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }]],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
      })
    ]
  }).then(bundle => {
    return bundle.write({
      dir: '.tmp/scripts/output',
      format: 'amd',
      name: 'library',
      sourcemap: true
    }).then(() => {
      return src('.tmp/scripts/output/main.js') // I did this because the path output was wrong. See: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2463
        .pipe($.replace(/require\(\['\.\//g, `require(['./scripts/output/`))
        .pipe(dest('.tmp/scripts'))
        .pipe(server.reload({ stream: true }));
    });
  });
};
```

this task generates all the files correctly, but I receive in the browser console the error

```
main.js:36 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Module ./scripts/output/file-0d52c3ae.js didn’t register its module
at singleRequire (main.js:36)
at async Promise.all (:9000/index 0)
at async require (main.js:43)
```

I'm not sure of what I should do now to fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem via the beautiful [Rich Harris shimport](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/shimport):

In the HTML I've done this:

```
<script src="/node_modules/shimport/index.js" data-main="scripts/lib/main.js"></script>
```

In `gulpfile.js` I've converted the `typescript` task in 3 tasks that are runned in series (I'm using gulp4). The compiling now is assigned to gulp (`gulp-typescript`) instead of rollup:

```
// $. is gulp-load-plugins: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-load-plugins

function typescript() {
  return src('app/**/*.ts')
    .pipe($.typescript({
      target: 'ES5',
      module: 'esNext',
      moduleResolution: 'node',
      rootDir: 'app/scripts/lib',
      outDir: '/builder',
      allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true
    }))
    .pipe(dest('app/scripts/'));
}

function buildLib() {
  return src('app/scripts/lib/**/*.js')
    .pipe(dest('app/scripts/builder/'));
}

function scripts() {
  return rollup.rollup({
    input: 'app/scripts/builder/main.js',
    external: ['jquery', '$'],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      babel({
        babelrc: false,
        presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }]],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
      })
    ]
  }).then(bundle => {
    return bundle.write({
      dir: '.tmp/scripts/lib',
      format: 'esm',
      name: 'lib',
      sourcemap: true,
      experimentalCodeSplitting: true,
      globals: {
        jquery: '$',
        $: 'jquery'
      }
    }).then(() => {
      return del(['app/scripts/builder']).then(() => {
        return src('.tmp/scripts/lib/main.js')
          .pipe(dest('.tmp/scripts'))
          .pipe(server.reload({ stream: true }));
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Now doing this all the files are compiled and put in the `/scripts/builder/` folder using esNext, so all the imports are untouched. And then rollupjs will convert the files for dynamic import and compatibility with babel.

Lastly, I delete the `/scripts/builder/` folder since is used only to create new valid fileds and the I execute all the three as a series:

```
// example
watch('app/scripts/**/*.ts', series(typescript, buildLib, scripts));
watch(['app/scripts/**/*.js', '!app/scripts/builder/**/*.js'], series(buildLib, scripts));
```

Hope I have helped someone, If you'd like to contribuite to make this code better I'm really up for it :)

Thanks!